# How to prove continuity of a following complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \gamma(t) $ be a holomorphic function on some region $ V\subset \mathbb{C} $ and define

$ f:V\times V\to\mathbb{R} $ by $$ f\left(z,w\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{|\gamma\left(z\right)-\gamma\left(w\right)|}{|z-w|} & z\neq w\\
|\gamma'\left(z\right)| & z=w
\end{cases}$$
I want to prove that $ f $ is continuous as a function of 2 complex variables. It is obvious that $ f$ is continuous for any $(z,w) $ such that $ z\neq w $. But Im struggling to prove continuity in points where $ z=w $.

I suppose it would be enough to prove that the function $$ f\left(z,w\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\gamma\left(z\right)-\gamma\left(w\right)}{z-w} & z\neq w\\
\gamma'\left(z\right) & z=w
\end{cases} $$ is continuous in $ \mathbb{C} $ and then use composition argument to conclude continuity in $ \mathbb{R} $, But im not sure how to prove it.

What bothers me is that I do not know how to work with the limit definition. Assume for example that I want to prove by definition continuity in a point $ (z,w) $ where $ z=w=z_0 $. Then I would want to show that $$ |f\left(z,w\right)-\gamma'\left(z_{0}\right)|\underset{\left(z,w\right)\to\left(z_{0},z_{0}\right)}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

But what can I do with $ f(z,w) $ ? it can alternate between $ \frac{\gamma\left(z\right)-\gamma\left(w\right)}{z-w} $ and $ \gamma'\left(z\right) $ infinitly many times, according to the path we approch $ (z_0,z_0) $ on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since continuity is local (and the only problem is proving continuity at $(z,z)$) and $V$ is open you can assume wlog that $V$ is an open ball, so in particular $V$ is convex; now you can use the fact that $$f(z,w)=\int_0^1\gamma'((1-t)w+tz)\,dt$$for *all* $z,w\in V$.

(Now if $(z_n,w_n)\to(z,w)$ the uniform continuity of $\gamma'$ on compact sets shows that $(1-t)w_n+tz_n\to(1-t)w+tz$ *uniformly*  for $t\in[0,1]$...)

**Edit:** Oops, I just noticed that you use the letter $f$ for two different functions! Bad idea - anyway, I'm referring to the second one, without the absolute values.

Comment: @FreeZe The case $z=w$ is the trivial case! If $z=w$ then $\int_0^1\gamma'((1-t)w+tz)\,dt=\int_0^1\gamma'(z)\,dt=\gamma'(z)$.

Comment: but $ z=w $ is not just a single case, when $(z_n,w_n)\to (z,w) $ we dont know in which path the values are getting closer to $ (z,w) $, it is not just one case where $ z_n=z $ and $ w_n = w $, this could happen many times while $ (z_n,w_n) $ strive to $ (z,w) $

Comment: @FreeZe So what? You're projecting the problems you had - this is a different proof. Nothing you say in that comment makes any difference at all! If $(z_n,w_n)\to(z,w)$ then, **regardless** of those things you say may happen, the uniform continuity of $\gamma'$ on compact sets shows that $(1-t)w_n+tz_n\to(1-t)w+tz$ _uniformly_  for $t\in[0,1]$

Comment: @FreeZe Maybe your comment was about why $f$ is given by that integral? I only explained the case $z=w$ because that was the only case you asked about. If $z\ne w$ you need the fundamental theorem of calculus.